# How do you graph the derivative of an implicit equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, implicit-differentiation

For example, say you have y^2+5x=6x^3+4

Okay, so we do some implicit derivation and get 18x^2-5 / 2y

Now... how is one to graph that? It is no longer y= or one function equaling another, it is now dy/dx= So... how is one to graph this? I'd like to do so to verify my answers are correct. My professor had no explanation other than "it won't work."

Comment: The function $\frac{18x^2-5}{2y}$ is a function of two variables. You can graph it in three dimensions by setting the expression equal to $z$, which represents the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at a given point $(x,y)$. It's not clear why you think graphing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ will help you "verify my answers are correct."

Comment: Thank you. I have not entered the 3 dimensional graphing world, yet.So perhaps what I'm asking is beyond my current understanding. To answer why you think it wouldn't be clear, typically I verify my derivatives by setting them equal to 0 on a graph and ensuring the result cross my critical points of my initial equation.

Comment: PS: Your vocabulary about this is confused. You do not take the derivative "of an implicit equation." You don't differentiate equations, you differentiate functions. You are determining the derivative of $y$, defined implicitly as a function of $x$. So what you mean is, how do you graph the derivative of $y$ when $y$ is defined implicitly as a function of $x$?

Comment: You can still verify your answers in that sense: just set $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to zero, solve the resulting equation, and check that the solutions correspond to critical points of the graph of the original equation. You don't need to have a graph of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to do this; you can do it algebraically.

Comment: Have you heard of a slope field?

Answer (score 3):

The equation $y^2+5x=6x^3+4$ defines implicitly two functions, namely, $f_1(x)=\sqrt{6x^3-5x+4}$ and $f_2(x)=-\sqrt{6x^3-5x+4}$. From implicit differentiation you know $$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{18x^2-5}{2y}\tag{1}$$
Then you get
$$f_1'(x)=\frac{18x^2-5}{2\sqrt{6x^3-5x+4}}\quad\text{and}\quad f_2'(x)=-\frac{18x^2-5}{2\sqrt{6x^3-5x+4}}$$
Both functions can be graphed in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Essentially, solve for y in the initial equation, then insert that into the implicit derivative. Thanks, I should have been able to think of that!

Comment: @Beethoven1111: this is an incomplete answer because it does not point out that you generally won't be able to solve for $y$ in the original equation --- that is the whole point of differentiating implicitly. If you could just solve for $y$, you could just differentiate as usual, without doing implicit differentiation. Change $y^2$ to $y^3$ and add a $y$ on the right-hand side, and then do that problem -- you'll be out of luck. In other words, this approach just won't work in general. It only works here because the equation defining $y$ implicitly is so trivial.

Comment: I see. If you cannot solve for y, there are no alternatives? From what I gather this may be because there is another plane involved.

Comment: The alternative is to do what I said in my comments above: interpret $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of two variables and graph in three dimensions.